# unable to parse xml data when description is large

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, zoho

In my project script it always runs smooth but only when the description is like this it gives "Unable to parse error" . or if there are high number of special character than such error also arises. I have already taken care of basic special characters . it will be great if you can tell me whats the prob lem with this description as it is always giving this error.

```
$description = "hi every one
now i will tell you what i want exactly
i want Development script for upload and sharing files like mediafire and mega 
i will tell you about every details what i need 
the websit or script will be dedicated to upload files, Whether been videos or photos or psd or pdf or mp3 every thing, i want members system in       the script, will be there normal members and premium members, premium members will be have more features more than normal member, you can see difference between them in this picture 
there are other things i want it in script 
like Control Panel for members and Control Panel  for admin 
contact us page, terms page & other pages like that 
linking the website in my account on Paypal to receive the money on him
this is the important things so i want tell me how much exactly will cost script like this"


<Leads>
<row no="1">
<FL val="Name">'XYZ'</FL>
<FL val="Email">'XYZ@ABC.COM'</FL>
<FL val="Country">'NEW JERSEY'</FL>
<FL val="Description">'.$description.'</FL>
</row>
</Leads>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in your script the CDATA.

```
<FL val="Description"><![CDATA['.$description.']]]]></FL>
```

Comment: Use in variable **$description** the function 
**htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_QUOTES);**